# Python3 'ModuleNotFoundError' when running the code through the terminal, but everything works as intended in a python virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, virtualenv

I am having problems with importing modules/packages with Python. I noticed this problem when I ran it in my terminal (CMD),
rather than my IDE (I use PyCharm). In PyCharm, I use a virtual enviroment setting with Python 3.7 and everything works as a charm 
and as intended.

For reference this is how the imports were done in `test_suite.py`:

```
...

from tests.scenarios.test_scenario_01 import TestScenario   # They work perfectly fine
from tests.scenarios.test_scenario_02 import TestScenario2    # written like this in PyCharm venv Python 3.7, but why?

...
```

This is a simplified version of my directory (without the unneccesary files):

```
QA System/
├── locators/
│   ├── locators.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── pages/
│   ├── pages.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── tests/
    ├── reports
    ├── test_scenarios
       ├── test_scenario_01.py
       ├── test_scenario_02.py
       ├── __init__.py
    |── test_suite.py
    |── __init__.py
```

However when running the file `test_suite.py` manually through my CMD (because I want to integrate it with Jenkins
eventually), I get this error (`py -3 test_suite.py`):

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests'`

Note: I am using the newest Python 3.7

From what I know about Python imports, for a directory to be treated like a python module, there needs to be a `'__init__.py'` file
 included in the same directory.

After a bit of research I found out that it is possible to do a different type of imports in Python 3 and tried it out (putting a `.`
 before the name of the imports). Like this:

```
from .scenarios.test_scenario_01 import TestScenario
from .scenarios.test_scenario_02 import TestScenario2
```

But still, it didn't run successfully and this was the error I've gotten:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.scenarios'; '__main__' is not a package`

Could you please help me out on this one?

TLDR: Imports work in a Python3.7 venv, but not outside it

Comment: can you show your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Comment: @Skaperen I am starting to think this might be the issue, I don't I have defined a PYTHONPATH env variable at all, and it is not in my Environment Variables list. I will look into it now.

Comment: I did some research, and my Python env variables are only "C:\Python2.7", "C:\Python2.7\Scripts", "C:\Users\zheko003\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32" and "/Scripts of the same python 37-32 directory.".

Comment: Maybe because you don't have the virtual environment activated in CMD. Find out which venv pycharm is using and activate it in CMD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by setting up a `PYTHONPATH` in system environment variables with the path to the project. As a value, I put the dir to the project. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

In case of directory It is mandate to use **init**.py. In modules it does not require to include **init**.py. Please, check what is your main directory and which is your modules..Hope this helps....